# More specific way to track companies on Google Analytics

Tags: events, google-analytics, analytics, tracking, service-provider

I'm job searching now, and I created a resume website which is a good way for me to track what companies are interested in me for. Also, I sometimes can tell which companies specifically have looked at me by going to the "Service Provider" dimension. However, sometimes they have a generic network (like Verizon or Charter) so I don't know. Is there another dimension, or is there another way for me to try to figure out which specific company is looking at me? In your answer, you don't have to be super specific because my question is pretty broad.

Comment: You could collect ip addresses and try to trace them back to a corporate network, but that's not always going to be accurate just like the service provider dimension.

Comment: @KevinB, collecting of IP addresses is against Google's terms of use. You cannot collect PII data. Also where would you find IP data in the first place in GA?

Comment: I did not say to do so with GA. ;)